# Laravel Middleware, one or another?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller and i'm using 3 middlewares inside my controller.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('isAgency');
    $this->middleware('isAdmin');
}
```

The problem is that Laravel applies all of them at once....if i'm logged in as admin i can't open the index and if i'm logged in as agency again i can't open the index. 
What i want is that user can be Admin or Agency to access all the functions inside this controller.

So is there some kind of a way to apply one or another middleware?
Like `if(isAdmin || isAgency)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is to options to do it
**option 1:** the simplest way is to create a new middleware that contains the three of them. for example

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   // either one of this meet
   if (Auth::user()->isAgency() || Auth::user()->isAdmin) {
       return $next($request);
   } 

   // return the response
}
```

**option 2:** is to use the parameters for the middleware it work only for laravel 5.* [laravel middleware parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple is that you can declare three different controllers for three middlewares

This can be used for `auth` controller

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This can be used for `isAdmin` controller

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->middleware('isAdmin');
}
```

This can be used for `isAgency` controller

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->middleware('isAgency');
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is quite similar what i have now! If i want to open some view i need to be that specific user....but i wan't for Admin user to be able to access everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using 2 middlewares in one controller with this solution:

In my middleware file before:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (Auth::user()->isAgency()) {
        return $next($request);
    } 

    abort(403);
}
```

and now i have added isAdmin() middleware so the admin can access everything:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if (Auth::user()->isAgency() || Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    } 

    abort(403);
}
```

and inside controller i just use middleware isAgency and admin is also included

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('isAgency');
}
```