# How can I allow access to users from 2 different auth guards using Laravel 8's basic.auth middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have module in Laravel 8 and I want to allow access to users from 2 different auth guards. For defining access I use middleware in module Controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth.basic:web');
    $this->middleware('auth.basic:cust');
}
```

As shown I am using basic.auth and 2 different guards: web and cust.
Auth guards are working across system and are configured correctly.

How to do multiple guard authentification in basic auth?
I tried a lot of things but i am stucket...pls help

I tried different syntaxes :  `$this->middleware(['auth.basic:web','auth.basic:cust']);`
Also custom middleware trying to get return result is auth successful :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->auth->guard('web')->basic('email');
   
    if( ! $this->auth->guard('web')->id()) {
        $this->auth->guard('cust')->basic('email');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Middleware, one or another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376498/laravel-middleware-one-or-another)

Comment: Unfortunately no because it is basic auth with 2 different guards. Each of them works ok separately. Problem is how to check in basic auth which guard it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you're using basic auth and 2 different guards: web and cust. But the default laravel auth uses the web guard. And I assume that you're trying that if condition in a middleware. If that's the case, then register your middleware in $routeMiddleware array.

Try it in the following way:

```
if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) 
{
     $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);

     return $this->auth->authenticate();
}
```

Then in the route you can do:

```
Route::middleware('multi.auth')->group(function () {
    // Routes accessible by users from both guards
});
```

Also, make sure you have properly configured guards in the `config/auth.php` file. They should be like the following:

```
'guards' => [
'guard1' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'provider1',
],

'guard2' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'provider2',
    ],
],
```

Please let me know if it worked or not. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I tried but without success. My middleware is ok in system but can not check auth
`<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as AuthFactory;

class AuthenticateBasicWebCust
{
    protected $auth;
    public function __construct(AuthFactory $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->guard = $this->auth->guard('cust')->check() ? 'cust' : 'web';
    }
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $this->auth->guard($this->guard)->basic('email');
        return $next($request);
    }
}`

Comment: Middleware and guards are correctly registered in system.
Result from code above is that it jumps to default web guard.  First check $this->auth->guard('cust')->check() returns null.